# how to run query that contain ( ' ) ? ex: select * from A where B like 'aa'bb'?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How do I run a query that contains ( ' ) ?

For example:

```
select * from A where B like 'aa'bb'
```

Working on Oracle 10g

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape a single quote by adding another quote before. Try:

`select * from A where B like 'aa''bb'`